# Getting value of multiple radio buttons groups javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a form which has to process a data filled in a by a client. It has a few radio groups and I'd like to get the value of it when it's changed.

```
<input type="radio" name="domain" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="domain" value="yes">

<input type="radio" name="hosting" value="no">
<input type="radio" name="hosting" value="yes">
```

I found a function like it somewhere, but it does not work the way I want.

```
    function getSelectedValueFor(name) {
        alert(document.getElementsByTagName(name).length);
        for (var i = 0; i <
            document.getElementsByTagName(name).length; i++) {
            var input = document.getElementsByTagName(name)[i];
                if (input.type == "radio" && input.checked) {
                    return input.value;
                }
        }
        return null;
}
```

It basically should work like this, and work for "getSelectedValueFor()" should be reusable:

```
$('input[name="hosting"]').change(function(){
    var x = getSelectedValueFor("hosting");
    console.log(x + " test");
    if(x == "yes") { $('#hosting').slideDown(); }
    else if(x == "yes") { $('#hosting').slideUp(); }
    return;
});
```

Is there anyone who can help me out? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you use JQuery?  Less lins of code and more browser compatiblity. - I can write you directly an example for that.

Comment: Use can not give `hosting` as a parameter in `getElementsByTagName`. It can be `input` and this is the reason your code is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply get selected value by using this line

```
var x = $('input[name="hosting"]:checked').val()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. Actually easier than expected though.